# webmail suite recommendation

Tags: imap, webmail, user-accounts

I have serveral emails in a few domains (email@domain1, email@domain2, email@domain3).

Currently they are on an owned email server and I am collecting emails via IMAP protocol (i would not like to use POP..) in Thunderbird.

I have a few partners and I want to allow them to access the same email address.

Here is what I desired:

> All users can open All the inboxes via IMAP @ Thunderbird (with proper configuration)
>
> at the same time, there are a webmail system, every user can login their account (userA, userB, userC),
>
> and they will see all inboxes (email@domain1, email@domain2, email@domain3)

Would you recommend any suite that fits my needs?

Either (a system to be installed on my server) or (a remote service where I need to config MX records) will do.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1):

I'm too running my own mail server and have tried numerous web mail suites.
What I recommend you is the [roundcube](http://roundcube.net/). It's configurable and sexy.
My setup is running on top of dovecot and postfix.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider [citadel](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php). Check out its list of features. Sounds like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I love my [SquirrelMail](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsquirrelmail.org%2F&ei=big9TOz2BYH88Abyu4GPBw&usg=AFQjCNHwGDB-f3FQT0s04V2Sv4WPzFctEg), it's got very few requirements, a simple interface, and gets the job done with minimal fuss. If you're looking for "oh shiny!" look elsewhere, this is a workhorse.

Support for simultaneous multiple mailboxes isn't there yet, it's being worked on in the development branch. You can configure it to use multiple backend servers, but you can only login to one at a time currently.